# Free word list for a word game

Tags: dictionary

In order to create a Scrabble-like mini game I need an English word list to validate entries.

I would like this list of words to be very extensive so just about any (within reason) English word will be represented.

Are there any lists like this available for free download and distribution?

Comment: Not only does this belong on Stackoverflow.com, it has already been asked there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594273/random-word-generator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this is for Scrabble!

[Take a look here](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

A search (Google) for "free English word list" (without the brackets) came up with quite a few hits.

The [first one](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/) looks promising, as does [this one](http://www.net-comber.com/wordurls.html).

I suggest you check out each one in turn until you find one you like.

Answer (score 2):

GNU [ASpell](http://aspell.net/) has a number of [dictionaries](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/0index.html) for many languages.

Answer (score 1):

On most Unix machines, there is a `/usr/share/dict/words` file installed that may be used.